# calculate each row with some values in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I am wondering how to properly do vector calculation in R.

I have a dataset like this.

```
            stay cops graduation
hinshi_#0  54722 6945      83674
hinshi_#1  13928 1798      21616
hinshi_#2    320   49        485
hinshi_#3  36010 4984      55184
hinshi_#4   7484  916      10618
hinshi_#5      6    0          6
hinshi_#6   6605  830       9741
hinshi_#7      2    0          5
```

and I have a list `l<-c(20124  2682 30138)` either.
What I want to do here is dividing each row of the datatable with the list.
Let me pick up the first row of the data,

```
 hinshi_#0  54722 6945      83674
```

I want them to be like `54722/20124, 6945/2682, 83764/30138`- calculate first value of vector with the first value of the list, same has to happen to second and third too. Any good way to deal with it? thanks.

Comment: *"and I have a list l<-c(20124  2682 30138)"* As this is not valid R code, can you clarify if `l` is a `list` or a `vector`?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is to transpose your data and than divide it by the vector. Something like t(dataset)/l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided I have understood you correctly, here is an option

```
l <- c(20124, 2682, 30138)

df / sapply(l, rep, each = nrow(df))
#                  stay       cops   graduation
#hinshi_#0 2.719241e+00 2.58948546 2.7763620678
#hinshi_#1 6.921089e-01 0.67039523 0.7172340567
#hinshi_#2 1.590141e-02 0.01826995 0.0160926405
#hinshi_#3 1.789406e+00 1.85831469 1.8310438649
#hinshi_#4 3.718943e-01 0.34153617 0.3523126949
#hinshi_#5 2.981515e-04 0.00000000 0.0001990842
#hinshi_#6 3.282151e-01 0.30947054 0.3232132192
#hinshi_#7 9.938382e-05 0.00000000 0.0001659035
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "stay cops graduation
'hinshi_#0'  54722 6945      83674
'hinshi_#1'  13928 1798      21616
'hinshi_#2'    320   49        485
'hinshi_#3'  36010 4984      55184
'hinshi_#4'   7484  916      10618
'hinshi_#5'      6    0          6
'hinshi_#6'   6605  830       9741
'hinshi_#7'      2    0          5", header = T)
```

Comment: thanks! it worked but I've got some warning too - `1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : first element used of 'each' argument`, I know it's just a warning but am just curious what it really means. thanks!

Comment: @user9191983 Based on the sample data you give, this should run without any warning. `each` is just the number of rows of your `data.frame` and is a scalar. Please double-check your data.

Answer (score 0):

`l` is a vector as provided(corrected) in @Maurits Ever 's answer. 
We can use `purrr`:

```
as.data.frame(purrr::map2(df,l,function(x,y) x/y))
```

**Result**(can be formatted to remove scientific display):

```
    stay       cops   graduation
1 2.719241e+00 2.58948546 2.7763620678
2 6.921089e-01 0.67039523 0.7172340567
3 1.590141e-02 0.01826995 0.0160926405
4 1.789406e+00 1.85831469 1.8310438649
5 3.718943e-01 0.34153617 0.3523126949
6 2.981515e-04 0.00000000 0.0001990842
7 3.282151e-01 0.30947054 0.3232132192
8 9.938382e-05 0.00000000 0.0001659035
```

Comment: thanks! ive tried but I see something wrong here...it looks like calculation is running between row and columns( not row with row) because ive got an error like `Error: 'x' (87) and '.y' (3) are different lengths`

Comment: Could you show what code you used?! It's hard to know as I'm only accessing a toy data set.